# pipe locate command and md5 output different checksum value

Tags: linux

I tried to pipe `locate` and `md5sum`command in Linux. But somehow it is not working. The output checksum from the piped command is not the same as I do it with `md5sum` alone. Please see the example below.

```
insieme@localhost:/tftpboot$ md5sum /tftpboot/somefile
63eb11647defc778d03731bcba8a7fcd  /tftpboot/somefile
insieme@localhost:/tftpboot$ locate somefile | md5sum
5c227c18859d12503bbd29beb698a33c  -
```

I must be doing something wrong, but cannot figure out what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're `md5sum`ming the `string` in the pipe, not the file; this does what you want:

```
md5sum $( locate somefile )
```